# SQL registro único

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

tengo un proyecto donde debo registrar las recomendaciones de un cliente a otro, de tal forma que tengo una tabla que controla si un cliente se ha registrado de parte de otro, y la fecha.

Bien, una limitación que tengo es que un cliente sólo puede ser recomendado una vez **NO SE CÓMO ESPECIFICARLO** en la creación de la tabla

Tengo estas tablas:

```
RECOMENDACION {cliente1,client2, fecharecomendacion}
CLIENTE{ ID, fecharegistro}
WEBCLIENT{nick,idUser,Startdate}
PREMIOCLIENTE {año_premio, importepremio}
```

Necesito hacer una consulta que me devuelve un vista con estos datos:

- idcliente que realiza la consulta,
- año de la información,
- total clientes recomendados,
- importe total recibido

Mi problema es que no consigo filtrar los clientes de recomendacion. Tengo esto:

```
select to_char(recommendationdate, 'yyyy') as AÑO, c.id as cliente,

  (select count(*) from client c2, recommendation r2 where r2.CLIENT1=c2.ID and c2.REGISTRATIONDATE is not null) REGISTRADO,

  (select count(*) from client c3, recommendation r3 where r3.CLIENT1=c3.ID and c3.REGISTRATIONDATE is  null) PENDIENTE

from webclient w, client c, recommendation r

where

  w.iduser = c.id and

  c.id=r.client1 and

  w.nick='ticaran'

group by

to_char(recommendationdate, 'yyyy'), c.id;
```

Comment: Tengo una confusión... tus tablas están en inglés o español? Lo otro, para poner esa "limitación" en la que un cliente sólo puede ser recomendado una vez, se soluciona poniendo como `PK` el **cliente 1 (si éste fuera el "recomendado")**

Comment: ok, solucionada la limitación. Ahora me falta la consulta
Tengo la lista de clientes con el nick `ticaran` y que se han registrado. Estos datos los saco de Webclient y RECOMMENDATION y me salen 13 registros.
El problema viene cuando quiero sacar contadores totales porque con select count(*) no me saca lo que necesito

Comment: No te saca lo que necesitas? Quieres decir que te trae información pero no la que esperas... deberías revisar las condiciones en ese caso, así vas descartando cual de todos los filtros te crea problema =/